# Ruby (Chef) Hash Array - Name is a Required Property

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to create a recipe to deploy Remote Desktop Services to Windows Servers, everything is working as expected apart from the Application deployment resource I created - it's a simple resource but I'm having a lot of issues passing the applications to be deployed as a hash array.

**attributes\default.rb**

```
default['app']['app_options'] = [
  {
    connection_broker: 'serv-01',
    options: {
      collectionname: 'Terminal Services',
      alias: 'Acrobat',
      displayname: 'Adobe Acrobat',
      filepath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat 11.0\\Acrobat\\Acrobat.exe',
      filevirtualpath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat 11.0\\Acrobat\\Acrobat.exe',
      commandlinesetting: 'DoNotAllow',
      iconindex: '0',
      iconpath: '\\\\serv-01\\C$\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat 11.0\\Acrobat\\Acrobat.exe',
      usergroups: ['domain\\group'],
      showinwebaccess: '1'
    }
  },
  {
    connection_broker: 'serv-01',
    options: {
      collectionname: 'Terminal Services',
      alias: 'Accounts',
      displayname: 'Accounts',
      foldername: 'Accounts',
      filepath: 'D:\\Accounts\\Accounts.bat',
      filevirtualpath: 'D:\\Accounts\\Accounts.bat',
      commandlinesetting: 'DoNotAllow',
      iconindex: '0',
      iconpath: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe',
      usergroups: ['domain\\group'],
      showinwebaccess: '1'
    }
  }
]
```

**recipes\remote_desktop.rb**

```
rdapps = node.read('app', 'app_options') || []

rdapps.each do |app|
  remote_desktop_apps app['options']['alias'] do
    action :create
    connection_broker app['connection_broker']
    app_options app['options']
  end
end
```

**resources\remote_desktop_apps.rb**

```
resource_name :remote_desktop_apps

property :connection_broker, String,
         desired_state: false

property :app_options, [String, Hash, Array],
         desired_state: false

action :create do
  app_options.each do |k,v|
          script << "New-RDRemoteApp -ConnectionBroker "#{connection_broker}" {-#{k.to_s.capitalize} #{v}}.join(' ')}"
  end
end
```

***Edit***

Thanks to @seshadri_c for the help past the first hurdle, I've hit another issue which seems related to the attributes.

Here is the output of a kitchen converge

```
================================================================================
       Error executing action `create` on resource 'remote_desktop_apps[Acrobat]'
       ================================================================================

   Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed
   ----------------------------------
   name is a required property

   Resource Declaration:
   ---------------------
   # In C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/windows_/recipes/remote_desktop.rb

    76:   remote_desktop_apps app['options']['alias'] do
    77:     action :create
    78:     connection_broker app['connection_broker']
    79:     app_options app['options']
    80:   end
    81: end

   Compiled Resource:
   ------------------
   # Declared in C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/windows_/recipes/remote_desktop.rb:76:in `block in from_file'

   remote_desktop_apps("Acrobat") do
     action [:create]
     default_guard_interpreter :default
     declared_type :remote_desktop_apps
     cookbook_name "windows_"
     recipe_name "remote_desktop"
     connection_broker "serv-01"
     app_options {"collectionname"=>"Terminal Services", "alias"=>"Acrobat", "displayname"=>"Adobe Acrobat", "filepath"=>"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat 11.0\\Acrobat\\Acrobat.exe", "filevirtualpath"=>"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat 11.0\\Acrobat\\Acrobat.exe", "commandlinesetting"=>"DoNotAllow", "iconindex"=>"0", "iconpath"=>"\\\\serv-01\\C$\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat 11.0\\Acrobat\\Acrobat.exe", "usergroups"=>["domain\\group"], "showinwebaccess"=>"1"}
   end
```

Then there's this message at the end of the run:

```
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: remote_desktop_apps[Acrobat] (windows_::remote_desktop line 76) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: name is a required property
$$$$$$ Exception calling "Read" with "3" argument(s): "Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection."
At line:100 char:11
$$$$$$ +       if ($fs.Read($bytes, 0, $fs.Length) -gt 0) {
$$$$$$ +           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
```

Comment: One thing I noticed is that custom resource actions usually call other Chef resources. So if you want to run a Powershell command, you should use [execute](https://docs.chef.io/resources/execute/) or [powershell_script](https://docs.chef.io/resources/powershell_script/) resource under `action :create do`.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with powershell_out and everything is working as expected. Appreciate your help!